# Сортировка элементов

Tags: php

Есть список который выводит текст через php

```
<div class="services">
                <?php foreach ($link->spec() as $item) { ?>
                    <div class="item">
                        <div class="s1"><?php echo $item->{$lang.'name'}; ?> <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="help ttip" title="<?php echo $item->page->{$lang.'anotation'}; ?>">?</a></div>
                        <div class="s2"><?php if ($item->service->period) { ?><?php echo $item->service->period; ?> <?php echo __('.'); ?><?php } else { ?>&nbsp;<?php } ?></div>
                        <div class="s3"><?php if ($item->service->price) { ?><?php echo $item->service->price; ?> <?php echo __(''); ?><?php } else { ?>&nbsp;<?php } ?></div>
                    </div>
                <?php } ?>
            </div>
```

Как сделать сортировку списка по price ? По убыванию

Comment: надо для начала отсортировать, а потом только выводить через `foreach`..... А т.к. вы это скорее всего выбираете из БД, то проще выбрать из БД сразу отсортировав как вам необходимо